# how to register an existing delta table to hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, cloudera-cdh, delta-lake, hiveddl

We are using spark for reading/writing data in delta format stored in HDFS (Databricks Delta table version 0.5.0).

We would like to utilize the power of Hive to interact with the delta tables.

**How can we register an existing data in delta format from a path on HDFS to Hive?**

Please note that currently we are running spark (2.4.0) on cloudera platform (CDH 6.3.3)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can do this so far is by registering it as an [unmanaged table](https://docs.databricks.com/lakehouse/data-objects.html#what-is-an-unmanaged-table). The most significant difference, as far as I can tell, is that if you drop an unmanaged table, it does not drop the underlying data.